# Scala Syntax for passing a Class to a function

Tags: scala

Can someone please explain this syntax in Scala?  I know "cd" is of a Class type and "_" is a wildcard, but what "<:" does here ?  Thanks.

```
   def func( cd: Class[_ <: CompressionCodec])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's used for Upper-type bound generics. This means that `_`has to be a subtype of `CompressionCodec`. Compared to lower-type bound generics which are written with `>:`, where it has to be a super type.

If you know Java you can think of them as `Class<? extends CompressionCodec>` for Upper-type bound generics and `Class<? super CompressionCodec>` for lower-type bound generics.

Check here for more! http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html